# Could not install Mobility gem on Rails plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-plugins, mobility

I'm creating a Rails plugin which uses Mobility gem.

I can see the installer listed when I do

```
rails generate --help
```

But then if I run

```
rails generate mobility:install
```

I get this totally weird error:

> Could not find generator 'mobility:install'. Maybe you meant 'mobility:install', 'binda:install' or 'devise:install'

My guess is that mobility generator isn't located in `lib/generators/mobility` but in `lib/generators/rails/mobility`. See the [github repository](https://github.com/shioyama/mobility/tree/master/lib). The issue does appear only on Rails plugin not on Rails application.

Any idea how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Can you please tell me which rails version you are using ?

Comment: @AjayBarot : it's Rails `5.1.2`

Comment: I think it's been sorted. See this [pull request](https://github.com/shioyama/mobility/issues/55#issuecomment-317159333)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected, the problem is the paths used for generators in Mobility. This [PR](https://github.com/shioyama/mobility/pull/56) will fix the issue.